# Get the month as a NSNumber from NSDate

Tags: objective-c

How would I get the month as a NSNumber from a NSDate object?  Not the current month but the month of the object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`NSCalendar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) for this purpose as the month of a date is dependant of the calendar being used. This will be the Gregorian calendar most of the time, but ah let's be super-correct. :)

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents comps = [cal components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"The month is: %d", [comps month]);
```

Comment: Haha, thanks, though I must say your approach appeals my geek-senses. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be a quick and dirty way:

```
NSInteger month = [[date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%m"
                                              timeZone:nil
                                                locale:nil] integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the NSDateFormatter to extract the month component of the date:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3600];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSLog(@"Month %d", [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] intValue]);
```